# Directive inside a angular-translate translation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-translate

I'm using [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) for i18n and want to use a directive inside a translation:

```
var translations = {
  TEST_1: 'Hello from <a href="/test">Test</a>',
  TEST_2: 'Hello from <user></user>'
};

app.directive('user', function() {
  return {
    template: '<a href="/test">Test</a>'
  };
});
```

Full plnkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jCCcvx7IEaAYUwyaQ7uH?p=preview

So

```
<p translate="TEST_1"></p>
<p translate="TEST_2"></p>
```

should be the same. The first (without directive) works, the second doesn't. It transcludes `<user></user>`, but Angular doesn't seem to be aware of it and doesn't do its directive magic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use the `translate-compile` directive:

```
<p translate="TEST_2" translate-compile></p>
```

From the [docs](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/05_using-translate-directive):

> Starting with version 2, the translation itself can be post processed
>   in context of the current scope (using $compile). This means any
>   directive used in a translation value itself will now work as
>   expected.